# Extract names of features and levels from a scikit-learn design matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to extract or compute the feature names and level names for a design matrix in scikit-learn? Here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4],
        'b': [5, 6, 7, np.nan],
        'c': ['u', 'v', 'u', 'v'],
        'd': [False, True, False, False],
        'e': ['r', 'r', 's', 's']
    }
)

scale_impute = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    SimpleImputer(strategy='median', add_indicator=True)
)

transformer = make_column_transformer(
    (scale_impute, ['a', 'b']),
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['c', 'e']),
    remainder='passthrough'
)

X = transformer.fit_transform(df)
```

At the console we see this:

```py
In [7]: df                                                                                                                                                      
Out[7]: 
     a    b  c      d  e
0  NaN  5.0  u  False  r
1  2.0  6.0  v   True  r
2  3.0  7.0  u  False  s
3  4.0  NaN  v  False  s

In [8]: pd.DataFrame(X)                                                                                                                                         
Out[8]: 
          0         1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
0  0.000000 -1.224745  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
1 -1.224745  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
2  0.000000  1.224745  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
3  1.224745  0.000000  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

where I've converted `X` to a data frame just for better printing. In this simple case I can figure out what each column is, but for more complicated scenarios it would be nice if there was some method to determine what each column corresponds to. In other words, for a given column in the design matrix, which feature does it correspond to? Is it a missing indicator column? If it corresponds to a categorical variable, which level does the column represent?

The `ColumnTransformer` class does have a `get_feature_names()` method, which seems like it might do what I want, but it doesn't work for this example:

```py
In [10]: transformer.get_feature_names()                                                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-20eb841d2d36> in <module>
----> 1 transformer.get_feature_names()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in get_feature_names(self)
    352                 raise AttributeError("Transformer %s (type %s) does not "
    353                                      "provide get_feature_names."
--> 354                                      % (str(name), type(trans).__name__))
    355             feature_names.extend([name + "__" + f for f in
    356                                   trans.get_feature_names()])

AttributeError: Transformer pipeline (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.
```

I'm running version 0.23.1 of scikit-learn.

I've seen the [patsy-learn](https://github.com/amueller/patsylearn) package, which might work, but I need to run my code on a university supercomputer where it's easier if I stick with packages that are bundled with Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep track of your features is to keep DataFrames for every single step of your pipeline.

- See [pd pipe](https://pdpipe.github.io/pdpipe/), it implements [sklearn_stages](https://pdpipe.github.io/pdpipe/doc/pdpipe/sklearn_stages.html) as well

When creating new features such as when using a One-Hot-Encoder, it becomes easy to keep track of where each feature comes from. i.e. `my_feature_x1`,`my_feature_x2`, ...